# How to list users having Review permission on content object?

Tags: plone, zope

Is there a quick way (catalog search) to list all the users/groups that have Review portal content permission on a content object?

Comment: try zopyx.plone.cassandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with a catalog query, since the only security relevant index in the catalog is "allowedRolesAndUsers" by default. This index only handles the "View" permission.

You can add your own index, with the exactly same implementation as the "allowedRolesAndUsers" Index, but check for "Review portal content". [See allowedRolesAndUsers implementation](https://github.com/do3cc/zope/blob/master/Products.CMFCore/trunk/Products/CMFCore/CatalogTool.py#L92)

If you do so, you have to patch the reindexObjectSecurity method, otherwise your index will not be updated on security relevant changes, like change roles thru the sharing view. 
[Here is an example how to patch it for Archetypes content](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.permissionmanager/blob/master/ftw/permissionmanager/patches.py) using [collective.monkeypatcher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.monkeypatcher/1.0.1)

Comment: Monkey patching ``reindexObjectSecurity`` is not needed, just add the new index the `_cmf_security_indexes` tuple. See https://github.com/collective/collective.localrolesdatatables/blob/8319deb4aef3d8db1803f1823071052130b28ce4/collective/localrolesdatatables/__init__.py#L3

Comment: @keul Yes, it's not necessary in the example above, the metadata gets updated too, that's the reason for the patch.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without adding a new index. Take a look at the approach on that product: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.portlet.truereview/